# yo mean:js express-model trying to create a controller instead of a model

Tags: node.js, express, meanjs, yo

I am trying to create a new model using the yo generator, using the below command:

```
yo meanjs:express-model category
```

When I run this, it is asking me:

```
Which module does this controller belongs to?
```

When I choose a module, it adds a model and a test file to that respective module. It should ideally create a new model and a test in a new "app" folder.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

try to use old version like 0.1.12

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.